Replace variables with values from a database in a string containing HTML
I have a string received from an editor, which includes HTML tags, like this:
const htmlString = "<div>Account <span contenteditable="false">{{account}}</span></div>. 
<div>Hello <span contenteditable="false">{{hello}}</span></div>"

In this content, there are two variables with the format {{account}} and {{hello}}.
In my database, I store variable data in the format { key: string, value: string, isDefault: boolean }:
[
   { "key" : "account", "value" : "", "isDefault" : true, },
   { "key" : "hello", "value" : "Hello everyone", "isDefault" : false }
]

First, I use a function to remove HTML tags:
const blockTags = /<(div|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|ul|ol|li|br)[^>]*>/gi;
const inlineTags = /<\/?(span|a|strong|em|b|i|u)[^>]*>/gi;

let content = htmlString.replace(blockTags, '\n').replace(/<\/(div|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p)>/gi, '\n');
content = content.replace(inlineTags, '');
content = content.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
content = content.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n').trim();

Then, I extract the variables:
const variables = (content.match(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/gi) || []).map((item) => item.replace(/\{\{|\}\}/g, ''));

Finally, I use a function to replace all variables with their corresponding values from the database, if variable is default (isDefault = true), i replace by dynamic value based on config by my system rule:
const objVariables = variables.reduce((acc, { key, value, isDefault }) => {
    acc[key] = { value, isDefault };
    return acc;
  }, {});

const result = content.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, (match, variable) => {
   const variableData = objVariables[variable];
   if (variableData && variableData.isDefault) {
      if (variable === "account") {
         return "ACCOUNT_NAME";
      }
    }
   return variableData ? variableData.value : match;
});

I want to replace all variables in the HTML string with the values stored in the database, but I think my code isn't the best solution and may be slow. I'm looking for an optimized solution or any suggestions.

I think you should just iterate over your variables and replace if they're found in the string... There's no need to strip tags.
EDIT:
Note that if you want to save your result with HTML, then this is the best option because it can also parse the variables in the HTML attributes like <div id="account-{{account}}">. Also, regardless of how the string is obtained, the code below works over a string, not the HTML itself.


const myVariables =
[
  { "key" : "account",  "value" : "",               "isDefault" : true  },
  { "key" : "hello",    "value" : "Hello everyone", "isDefault" : false },
];

let myString = myContent.innerHTML;

myVariables.forEach
(
  ( { key, value, isDefault } ) => myString = myString.replaceAll
  (
    `{{${key}}}`,
    (
      ( isDefault && ( key === 'account' ) )
      ? 'ACCOUNT_NAME'
      : value ?? key
    )
  )
);

// You can keep the parsed string. This is just for show:
myContent.innerHTML = myString;
console.log('New String (with HTML):', myString);
<div id="myContent">
  <div id="account-{{account}}">Account <span contenteditable="false">{{account}}</span>.</div>
  <div>Hello <span contenteditable="false">{{hello}}</span></div>
</div>



Note that in the example above the html was not even touched.
EDIT: Updated Answer
If you want only the text fragments (stripping all HTML tags), you can achieve almost the same way as the above function. See below:


const myVariables =
[
  { "key" : "account",  "value" : "",               "isDefault" : true  },
  { "key" : "hello",    "value" : "Hello everyone", "isDefault" : false },
];

// This string is just an example. Don't bother with the structure I used.
let myString = // No line-breaks.
  '<div>Account: <span contenteditable="false">{{account}}</span></div>'+
  '<div>Greeting: <span contenteditable="false">{{hello}}</span></div>';

// Let the browser strip the HTML for you...
let virtualElement = document.createElement('body');
{
  virtualElement.innerHTML = myString
    // You can uncomment the code line below,
    // but you'll see double line-breaks often.
    //.replaceAll(/<(div|h[1-6]|p|br)[^>]*>/gi, '\n')
    .replaceAll(/<\/(div|h[1-6]|p)>/gi, '\n');
  
  // The browser strips all other html tags...
  myString = virtualElement.textContent;
}
virtualElement = null;

// Remains the same as the previous example...
myVariables.forEach
(
  ( { key, value, isDefault } ) => myString = myString.replaceAll
  (
    `{{${key}}}`,
    (
      ( isDefault && ( key === 'account' ) )
      ? 'ACCOUNT_NAME'
      : value ?? key
    )
  )
);

// Output
console.log(myString);



But, if you want to retain the HTML (untouched) and just change the text fragments, you can do as below:


const myVariables =
[
  { "key" : "account",  "value" : "",               "isDefault" : true  },
  { "key" : "hello",    "value" : "Hello everyone", "isDefault" : false },
];

// This string is just an example. Don't bother with the structure I used.
let myString =
  '<div>Account: <span contenteditable="false">{{account}}</span></div>'+"\n"+
  '<div>Greeting: <span contenteditable="false">{{hello}}</span></div>'+"\n";

// TEST:
const newString = evaluateString(myString);

// Inserting with HTML in the document:
document.body.innerHTML = newString;

// Showing in the console:
console.log(newString);

// Remains almost the same as the previous example...
// But wrapped in a function.
function parseString ( myString )
{
  myVariables.forEach
  (
    ( { key, value, isDefault } ) => myString = myString.replaceAll
    (
      `{{${key}}}`,
      (
        ( isDefault && ( key === 'account' ) )
        ? 'ACCOUNT_NAME'
        : value ?? key
      )
    )
  );
  
  return myString;
}

// New function
function evaluateString ( myString )
{
  const virtualElement = document.createElement('body');
  virtualElement.innerHTML = myString;
  
  return evaluateTexts(virtualElement).innerHTML;
  
}

// New function
function evaluateTexts ( myElement )
{
  for ( const childNode of myElement.childNodes )
  {
    if ( childNode.nodeName == '#text' )
    {
      childNode.textContent = parseString(childNode.textContent);
    }
    
    else
    {
      evaluateTexts(childNode);
    }
  }
  return myElement;
}




Thank you for your answer! However, the content I receive is a string rather than HTML, so I need to remove HTML tags before replacing variables. Your solution reduces the loop, but I think this code is more concise, but it seems to increase the complexity of the algorithm.

You need just the text without HTML tags?

Yes, after I receive content from text editor, I will publish this content to Facebook Page using graph API. If I using textarea tag, i can't add variable to content, so I need using text editor

@huong1412 I just added two more options of code. The first new one is what you're looking for. I'll add just a little change to break lines where there're block tags...
